# How to get all InputTypes in EditText dynamically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I want to fetch all possible InputTypes available for EditText dynamically.

I have checked out couple of links, I know how to setInputTypes through xml or dynamically, how to fetch all types of InputTypes?

I have checked the InputType.class too, didnt't find any such method in it. Still is it possible to get all the InputTypes?

Thanks

Comment: if there is setInputType there should  be getInputType as well

Comment: getInputType fetches the input type which is set on that edittext, I'm asking for all possible InputTypes.

Comment: InputType has all constants but there is no method to get them all

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you need this, and probably there is a better solution to your problem, but here is an example using reflection, sans the exception handling:

```
for (Field f : InputType.class) {
  nt mod = f.getModifiers();
  if (Modifier.isStatic(mod) && Modifier.isPublic(mod) && Modifier.isFinal(mod)) {
    //do something with this
    f.getName();
  }
}
```